# Jsoup printing each <div> content in a separate line

Tags: java, jsoup

I have been working on a web link with java jsoup library to extract some parts of it.

This is the part which I work on it.

```
<div class="adv_side_price">
  100,000 ريال 
</div>
<div class="adv_side_price">
  16,000 ريال 
</div>
<div class="adv_side_price">
  16,000 ريال 
</div>
<div class="adv_side_price">
  16,000 ريال 
</div>
<div class="adv_side_price">
  37,000 ريال 
</div>
<div class="adv_side_price">
  150,000 ريال 
</div>
<div class="adv_side_price">
  60,000 ريال 
</div>
<div class="adv_side_price">
  119,000 ريال 
</div>
```

The output should be as following:

100,000

19,500

37,000

150,000

60,000

119,000

10,000

I used the following  code

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.bezaat.com/ksa/riyadh/cars/all/1").get();
 System.out.println("Price"+doc.select("div.adv_side_price").text().replace("ريال",""));
```

But output gained as one line

```
Price 100,000  19,500  37,000  150,000  60,000  119,000  10,000
```

Could someone possibly helps please

Comment: Did you try the split(" ") method on the string 100,000  19,500  37,000  150,000  60,000  119,000  10,000 ?

Comment: It 's not the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try printing content of each div using separate `println` call like

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.bezaat.com/ksa/riyadh/cars/all/1").get();
for (Element el : doc.select("div.adv_side_price"))
    System.out.println(el.text().replace("ريال", ""));
```

Comment: If I want to system out print     both      doc.select("div.adv_content").select("div.adv_content_details").text()   +" "                                                & doc .select("div.adv_side_price")) adjacently could it be done?

Comment: @JavaFan Sorry I am not sure what you mean. Maybe post another question about it where you will explain what you want to achieve in more details.

Comment: I posted my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458018/jsoup-extracting-two-div-gives-iterated-redundant-output-when-using-loop